# Pandas - Least frequent value in column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a Pandas series of integers, 'win'. I want the values most_common and least_common to be the most and least frequent values in the column. for example, with the following numbers, I would want most_common to be 2 and least_common to be 1. If it is a tie (either way) then this can be broken arbitrarily.

```
0 1 2 2 2 0 0 2 2 0
```

I can find most_common using the following code:

```
win.mode()[0]
```

How can I find the least common? I tried the following code, but it did not work, and in any case I was not sure if this was the best way to go about this:

```
lowest =valid_loss.value_counts().tail(1)[0]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think need last value of index for lowest value and first index for top value:

```
valid_loss = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0])

s = valid_loss.value_counts()
print (s)
2    5
0    4
1    1
dtype: int64

highest = s.index[0]
print (highest)
2

lowest = s.index[-1]
print (lowest)
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way is using the [value_counts](https://devdocs.io/pandas%7E1/reference/api/pandas.dataframe.value_counts) api

```
valid_loss = pd.Series([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0])

lowest = valid_loss.value_counts(ascending=True)[0]
>> 1
```